# Change from date and hour format to numeric format

Tags: r, date, time

I am working in R and I need to change from a column in format

```
9/27/2011  3:33:00 PM
```

to a value format. In Excel I can use the function `value()` but I do not know how to do it in R.

My data looks like this:

```
9/27/2011 15:33 a   1   5   9
9/27/2011 15:33 v   2   6   2
9/27/2011 15:34 c   3   7   1
```

Comment: To get a complete answer, give us the output of `dput(yourData)` so we can recreate your data object exactly. The answer given will vary depending on the column type, as it may currently be a factor or character. If it is in fact already a date or POSIX column, something like `as.numeric()` should work I think. For example: > `as.numeric(Sys.time()) [1] 1321895128`

Answer (score 30):

To convert a string into R date format, use `as.POSIXct` - then you can coerce it to a numeric value using `as.numeric`:

```
> x <- as.POSIXct("9/27/2011  3:33:00 PM", format="%m/%d/%Y  %H:%M:%S %p")
> x
[1] "2011-09-27 03:33:00 BST"
> as.numeric(x)
[1] 1317090780
```

The value you get indicates the number of seconds since an arbitrary date, usually 1/1/1970.  Note that this is different from Excel, where a date is stored as the number of days since an arbitrary date (1/1/1900 if my memory serves me well - I try not to use Excel any more.)

For more information, see `?DateTimeClasses`

Answer (score 5):

This was useful for me:

```
> test=as.POSIXlt("09/13/2006", format="%m/%d/%Y")
> test
[1] "2006-09-13"
> 1900+test$year
[1] 2006
> test$yday
[1] 255
> test$yday/365
[1] 0.6986301
> 1900+test$year+test$yday/366
[1] 2006.697
```

You can use similar approaches if you need day numbers like in Excel.