# Change from date time to numeric AND back to date time in R

Tags: r, datetime

**Seeing that others can't reproduce this** Any speculation about system settings that might cause what I'm seeing would be appreciated. This is on a work PC configured by IT, but I will compare with my personal install this evening and then update the question.

Using base R, I'm trying to read in date and time, convert to numeric, and then convert back to date time.  The problem I'm running into is a + 5 hour shift that gets introduced, I think due to timezone defaults.

From a previous question, an example of date time to numeric was provided:
[Change from date and hour format to numeric format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215404/change-from-date-and-hour-format-to-numeric-format)

```
> x <- as.POSIXct("9/27/2011  3:33:00 PM", format="%m/%d/%Y  %H:%M:%S %p")
> x
[1] "2011-09-27 03:33:00 EDT"
> y <- as.numeric(x)
[1] 1317108780
```

**Typo in above code fixed*

When I try to bring this back to date time, I get:

```
> z <- as.POSIXct(y, origin="1970-01-01")
> z
[1] "2011-09-27 08:33:00 EDT"
```

I tried some variants, including specifying time zones explicitly, but am consistently getting this shift.

Comment: I can't reproduce this (after fixing the assignment in `y -> as.numeric(x)` to `<-`).

Comment: read `?strptime` : "%p : AM/PM indicator in the locale. Used in conjunction with %I and not with %H" I don't know if it will solve your problem but still, you can begin by changing your `%H` in `%I`...

Comment: Thanks CathG.  I will not be using %p with my own data, that is based off the previous linked question for the benefit of others.  I get this shift in all cases tried, including using `%T` with my own data.

Comment: what is your `Sys.timezone()` ?

Comment: `> Sys.timezone()`
`[1] "EST"`

Comment: see the answer I posted, do you have the 5 hours shift if you specified the `tz` in the first call to `as.POSIXct` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is just a problem of specifying time zones :

```
x <- as.POSIXct("9/27/2011  15:33:00", format="%m/%d/%Y  %H:%M:%S")
> as.POSIXct(as.numeric(x), origin="1970-01-01",tz="EST") # as.numeric(x)=1317130380
[1] "2011-09-27 08:33:00 EST"
```

but :

```
x <- as.POSIXct("9/27/2011  15:33:00", format="%m/%d/%Y  %H:%M:%S",tz="EST")
> as.POSIXct(as.numeric(x), origin="1970-01-01",tz="EST") # as.numeric(x)=1317155580
[1] "2011-09-27 15:33:00 EST"
```

*remark : I simplified 03:33:00 PM in 15:33:00*

Comment: Must be something with my system `> x <- as.POSIXct("9/27/2011  3:33:00", format="%m/%d/%Y  %H:%M:%S", tz="EST")`
`> as.POSIXct(as.numeric(x), origin="1970-01-01",tz="EST")`
`[1] "2011-09-27 08:33:00 EST"`

Comment: Thanks for poking at it, CathG.  I will verify against my system at home, maybe some others around the office, to see if I can narrow it down.

Comment: IT updated my R version from something slightly outdated to 3.1.0 and the issue went away.  Thanks again for investing a bit of time.

Comment: @joeln thanks for letting me know ! I'm glad you don't have the problem anymore, although it doesn't explain why you had it... (well, just a version problem I guess !)