# Issue in converting date format to numeric format in R

Tags: r

I had a dataset that looked like this:

```
#df 

id       date
1       2016-08-30 10:46:46.810
```

I tried to remove the hour part and only keep the date. This function worked:

```
df$date <-  format(as.POSIXct(strptime(df$date,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) ,format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

and the date now look likes this

```
id      date
1       2016-08-30
```

Which is something that I was looking for. But the problem is I wish to do some calculation on this data and have to convert it to integer:

```
   temp <-  as.numeric(df$date )
```

It gives me the following warning:

```
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

and results in

```
NA
```

Does anyone know where the issue is?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215404/change-from-date-and-hour-format-to-numeric-format)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty easy as you have a standard format (see [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)) which *inter alia* the [anytime](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/anytime.html) package supports (and it supports other, somewhat regular formats):

```
R> library(anytime)
R> at <- anytime("2016-08-30 10:46:46.810")
R> at
[1] "2016-08-30 10:46:46.80 CDT"
R> ad <- anydate("2016-08-30 10:46:46.810")
R> ad
[1] "2016-08-30"
R>
```

The key, though, is to understand the *relationship between the underlying date formats*.  You will have to read and try a bit more on that.  Here, in essence we just have

```
R> as.Date(anytime("2016-08-30 10:46:46.810"))
[1] "2016-08-30"
R>
```

The [anytime](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/anytime.html) package has a few other tricks such as automagic conversion from integer, character, factor, ordered, ...

As for the second part of your question, your were *so close* and then you spoiled it again with `format()` creating a *character* representation.

You almost always want *`Date`* representation instead:

```
R> ad <- as.Date(anytime("2016-08-30 10:46:46.810"))
R> as.integer(ad)
[1] 17043
R> as.numeric(ad)
[1] 17043
R> ad + 1:3
[1] "2016-08-31" "2016-09-01" "2016-09-02"
R>
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about `anytime`.

Comment: I just added a wee bit more. The key, *really*, as that you can _compute_ on `Date` and `POSIXct` types -- but not on characters.  So the key is to _easily_ parse to `Date` and `POSIXct`, and that is where [anytime](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/anytime.html) shines.

Comment: Thank you so much Dirk Eddelbuttel and Jason! anytime has all the functions that I was looking for today.

Answer (score 1):

Not `format()`. `format` gives you a character vector (string), and this confuses `as.numeric` because there are weird non-numeric characters in there. As far as the parser is concerned, you might as well have asked `as.numeric("ripe red tomatoes")`.

Use `as.Date()` instead. e.g.

```
as.Date(as.POSIXct(df$date, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Comment: You need to show him how to parse his input, though, which is pretty easy in his case.

Comment: Thanks! Clarified.

Comment: `as.Date()` on `POSIXct` objects can be dangerous if you hit timezone movements. Beware - `as.Date(as.POSIXct("2000-01-01 00:00", tz="Australia/Brisbane"))`

Comment: Correct. `anydate()` throws the one `as.POSIXlt()` in there you need to go _with TZ_ information.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel - great... I was just about to check how your package dealt with that issue.

Comment: That was a bug fix, actually.  If you have a moment to spare, though, I have been stumped by [issue #5](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/anytime/issues/5) which has a down-under context. Care to take a peek?  I cannot replicate, even when setting my TZ etc pp

Comment: I'm peeking now. In Sydney. Where we recently moved to DST. :)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel - sure... I'll take a geezer.