# Converting an integer date

Tags: r, date

My question doesn't have to do with my own dataset, but since I'm new to R, I wanted to make sure I knew how to work with dates, so I'm searching up the different ways to manipulate and compare dates in R.
 I recently read an answer to a question regarding converting a date into an integer date using the as.numeric () function. Here is the answer that was accepted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8215581/10864249
So from that answer, my understanding is that the date was converted into seconds. 
Why would anyone want to use the as.numeric() function if we're going to only get seconds?
Can we convert the integer date into a smaller integer, like # of days by just dividing by 365.25 or by months even by dividing by 12, then? I assume it'd be easier to compare dates that way, rather than in seconds.

Thanks!!

Comment: Please take a look at the `lubridate` package. The beauty about(of?) R is the variety and choice available.

Comment: Please take a look at the `?DateTimeClasses`, `?strptime`, `?as.Date` in `base` before learning other packages according to dates.

Answer (score 0):

coercing a date object into a numeric object will give you "the number of days since 01/01/1970"

```
my_date = as.Date('2015-01-01')

my_date

#[1] "2015-01-01"

class(my_date)

# [1] "Date"

as.numeric(my_date)

# [1] 16436
```